# Conditionally invalid member function of class template (implicit instantiation works; explicit instantiation fails)

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

I created a class template. Depending on its template arguments it supports different operations. The class template shall be (*implicitly*) instantiated for several combinations of template arguments. For some of those combinations there may be member functions that do not make sense (and also do not compile). However, as long as I do not enforce *explicit* instantiation, everything seems to work as desired.

Now, there are these scary cases called "unspecified", "undefined", "ill-formed; no diagnostic required", …. I definitely want to avoid any of those things. So I am asking for an advice how to deal with this situation.

Here is an example that shows the same observation. Please note that I am not so much interested in how to fix this exact toy example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct SingleSink {
  SingleSink(T) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class T>
struct DoubleSink {
  DoubleSink(T, T) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class T, int arity /*, some other stuff */>
struct SuperSink {
// This class shall do something special depending on, say, `arity`.
// Instead of partially specializing the whole class template (and introducing
// code duplication for the remaining functionality), let us externalize the 
// `arity`-dependent behavior to a special member.

  using Sink = std::conditional_t<
    arity == 1,
    SingleSink<T>,
    DoubleSink<T>
  >;

  Sink sink_;

// [some more data members that do not depend on `arity`]

// for a fixed `Sink` one of the following constructors should fail to compile
  SuperSink(T i) : sink_{i} {}
  SuperSink(T i, T j) : sink_{i, j} {}
// ... so these are what I call "conditionally invalid member functions".
};

// explicit instantiation yields error (deactivated by comments):
// template struct SuperSink<int, 1>;
// template struct SuperSink<int, 2>;

int main() {
// implicit instantiation works
  SuperSink<int, 1>{5};
  SuperSink<int, 2>{5, 6};

// these yield a compile error (as desired)
// SuperSink<int, 1>{5, 6};
// SuperSink<int, 2>{5};
}
```

1. Are these conditionally invalid member functions a problem if I never
   need explicit instantiation?
2. If yes: is it good practice to check that explicit instantiation works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these conditionally invalid member functions a problem if I never need explicit instantiation?

Even templates from STL have "invalid" methods, for example: `std::vector<T>::resize(std::size_t)` with non default constructible `T`.

So, with "invalid" methods, your class is usable normally. Document your requirement is an option.

But then, those methods are not SFINAE friendly, as error would not appear in immediate context, but in instatntiation.

You might use SFINAE on your own to remove them when invalid, for example:

```
template <std::size_t N = arity, std::enable_if_t<N == 1, int> = 0>
SuperSink(T i) : sink_{i} {}

template <std::size_t N = arity, std::enable_if_t<N != 1, int> = 0>
SuperSink(T i, T j) : sink_{i, j} {}
```

In C++2a, you might specify some condition to include methods in the class (Similar to above SFINAE, but with a nicer syntax and no extra template):

```
SuperSink(T i) requires (arity == 1) : sink_{i} {}

SuperSink(T i, T j) requires (arity != 1) : sink_{i, j} {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see at least the problem, that the design breaks type traits like the following, so you will probably get problems when SFINAE is used to decide which constructors will be called.

```
static_assert(!std::is_constructible<SuperSink<int, 1>, int, int>::value);

static_assert(!std::is_constructible<SuperSink<int, 2>, int>::value);
```

You could fix this by inverting the design: Define `SingleSink` and `DoubleSink` as special cases (or if needed: specialisations) of a generic `SuperSink`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, int arity>
struct SuperSink {

 template<typename... Ts, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == arity> >
  SuperSink(Ts... is) {
       std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

};


template<typename T>
struct SingleSink : SuperSink<T, 1> {
    using Base = SuperSink<T, 1>;
    using Base::Base; // inherit constructor
    // implement special functionality here
};


template<typename T>
struct DoubleSink : SuperSink<T, 2> {
    // follow same pattern as in SingleSink.
}


int main() {
    // implicit instantiation works
    SuperSink<int, 1>{5};
    SuperSink<int, 2>{5, 6};

    // Now, these work as desired
    static_assert(!std::is_constructible<SuperSink<int, 1>, int, int>::value);

    static_assert(!std::is_constructible<SuperSink<int, 2>, int>::value);

    // these yield a compile error (as desired)
    //  SuperSink<int, 1>{5, 6};
    // SuperSink<int, 2>{5};
}
```

Comment: Interesting that the SFINAE constructor checks fail. This is one argument to avoid the conditionally invalid member functions.

Comment: My toy example was not ideal, sorry. The pattern of either a `SingleSink` or a `DoubleSink` member evolved because I wanted to specialize some of the functionality of `SuperSink`. A `SuperSink` is supposed to do much more than what the `Sink` member does. Instead of partially specializing the whole class template I am trying to externalize the relevant behavior to that member (in order to avoid code duplication for common functionality). Thus the inverted design does not help in the "real" case I have in mind. I added some code comments to my toy example to explain that.

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting. I had to check it, too.

Comment: if understand you correctly, you could derive the `SingleSink` and `DoubleSink` from `SuperSink` then. See my updated example.

Comment: I have the opposite in mind: `SuperSink` shall provide lots of functionality. The behavior can be customized by template parameters, but the user code should only interact with `SuperSink`s. `SingleSink` and `DoubleSink` customize a small part of the internal functionality of `SuperSink`. Anyway, my question is just about the "conditionally invalid constructor". In practice, it is a bit more difficult to `std::enable_if` them according to the specific `Sink` (and I considered not to use SFINAE here). Sorry again for my imperfect example. Probably too late to correct(=rewrite) now.

Comment: OK, I see. Of course I don't know all the details of your use-case, but what you write smells like CRTP could be what you want.